# Ways to implement large settings dialog with WPF and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am building an extensible WPF + MVVM application that will possibly have a significant number of user settings (from both core of the application and plugins). From my previous experience I can tell that managing options dialogs is pain when the application grows. Are there any best practices or design patterns that I could follow? How other applications like Visual Studio implement options dialogs with large number of categories and settings? Are these dialogs generated at runtime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar issue in the past, and went for the `PropertyGrid` in the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).

This lets you bind the grid to an object, containing all of your configurable properties and will auto-populate the grid based on those properties. You can provide templates for custom editors too.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of PropertyGrid. I use it myself and it works great in certain cases. However, in this case I am more interested in good strategies to come up with something similar to Visual Studio options dialog that has many categories and settings. I always could create such dialog by hand, but I think it will be a nightmare to maintain it later.

Comment: hmmm, not too sure then I'm afraid, I agree, hand crafting something will be very arduous and to come up with something dynamic you're effectively reproducing the `PropertyGrid`. Are you using any sort of DI in your application?

Comment: Not at this time. However, I assume some kind of IOC will be needed very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Start with dialogs with quite few items, so it is later easier to add more items, without making the user needed to search the changed positions (or even finding it in other dialogs which are split).